# defining gcd on rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, rngs

I see that in most textbooks they say let $R$ be an integral domain and start defining the greatest common divisor. My question is, can gcd's be defined on just commutative rings without an identity?

Comment: See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#The_gcd_in_commutative_rings).

Comment: An example would be the ring of all even integer (i.e. $2\mathbb{Z}$) and the usual GCD.